# php UPDATE not working query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm have a php script that does the following:
It selects all the data from a table. If the rows are greater than 0, the data must be updated, otherwise it makes a new row of data. Making the new of data works, only the update does not run.
Here's my code:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "******";
$password = "*********";
$database = "elektrowinkel";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Er kan geen connectie gelegd worden met $host");

mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die("databank $database niet beschikbaar");

$queryRijen = "SELECT * FROM stock_fysieke_winkels
                  WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "' and
                        Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'";

$rijen = mysqli_query($link, $queryRijen);

$resultaat = mysqli_num_rows($rijen);

if (mysqli_num_rows($rijen) > 0)
{
$query = "UPDATE stock_fysieke_winkels
          Set Aantal = '" .$_POST['aantal']. "'
          WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "',
                Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'";
}   
else
{
$query = "INSERT INTO stock_fysieke_winkels (Fysieke_winkel_ID, Product_ID, Aantal)               
        VALUES ('". $_POST['winkel'] . "', '" . 
                    $_POST['product']. "', '" .
                    $_POST['aantal']. "')";

echo "Er is een nieuw product toegevoegd bij winkel ". $_POST['winkel'] . "" ;
}

mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `AND` is missing in your update code. try this :- `$query = "UPDATE stock_fysieke_winkels Set Aantal = '" .$_POST['aantal']. "' WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "' AND Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'";`

Comment: It's great that you're using a modern API, but now take a look at prepared statements. Also look at INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment that you missed Operator `AND` in your query. Because multiple condition are there so you need to add `AND`. do like this:-

```
$query = "UPDATE stock_fysieke_winkels Set Aantal = '" .$_POST['aantal']. "' WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "' AND Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'";
```

Note:- if any one of them is needed then you can use `OR` instead of `AND`.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to change you update query with this:

`UPDATE stock_fysieke_winkels
    Set Aantal = '" .$_POST['aantal']. "'
    WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "' 
    AND Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'`

use the keyword "AND" to combine multiple condition on "WHERE" clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the keyword AND/OR between Where clause. Rewrite the below update query

```
$query = "UPDATE stock_fysieke_winkels
          Set Aantal = '" .$_POST['aantal']. "'
          WHERE Fysieke_winkel_ID = '". $_POST['winkel'] . "' OR/AND
                Product_ID = '" . $_POST['product']. "'";
```